# Error by converting date: Unparseable date in JAVA

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, exception

I can't find the problem. I'm trying to convert the date:

"Thu, 10 Jul 2014 13:33:26 +0200"

from string to Date with this code:

```
String formatType = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
Date startzeit = new SimpleDateFormat(formatType).parse(einsatz.getString("startzeit"));
```

but I'm getting this exceptoin:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 10 Jul 2014 13:33:26 +0200"`

Comment: Whats your default locale?At times due to the locale the string isn't parsed properly.Try this Date startzeit = new SimpleDateFormat(formatType,Locale.ENGLISH).parse(einsatz.getString("startzeit"));

Comment: side note: you IDE should give you a warning for using SimpleDateFormat without a locale.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a `SimpleDateFormat` without specifying a locale, so it'll use the default locale. By the looks of your variable names, that may not be English - so it'll have a hard time parsing "Thu" and "Jul".

Try:

```
String formatType = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
Date startzeit = new SimpleDateFormat(formatType, Locale.US)
                        .parse(einsatz.getString("startzeit");
```

(That works for me, with your sample value.)